# how can i use IE (or different browser) for each webbrowser controle?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, browser

i want to use different browsers for my webbrowser controls in c#.NET.
for example, if im log into facebook from the webbrowser1, i will not in the webbrowser2

if i cant use ie different for each webbrowser... can i separate cookies for each webbrowser control?
for example, if i navigate using the first controle

```
    webbrowser1.navigate("this is not important");
```

then submit the login form

```
webbrowser1.document.getelem..... click
```

thats will not applicated on the secod control( webbrowser2)

<strike>-</strike>

i hope you inderstand what i want :)

Answer (score 0):

The WebBrowser control is a wrapper around IE and will always and only use IE. It's never going to use Firefox or Chrome etc. Some browsers apart from IE may allow Automation, but you'll have to check their documentation.

In your two lines of code, both are using the control called webbrowser1, so the Navigate and getelement will always go to the control. If you want to use two browser instances, you need to have 2 controls.

I don't clearly understand what your question is. The two points above are what I can answer.

Comment: emmmmm, about sessions.... thats what i want to say :)
i mean if a session in facebook opened by webrowser1... but i want to open other session in the same website (facebook in this exampl) with webbrowser2... can i do that ?? or just one session (because of using the same browser (IE)) ?

Comment: You should test it, but I believe that you'll have the same session, yes.